how to get fish smell out of cast iron skillet
When I cook fish fillets in my cast iron griddle skillet, the skillet smells like fish even after I clean it.  Is there a way to get that fish smell out?
I clean the skillet by first putting water in the pan for about 10 mins, then I use a paper towels to wipe the pan to clean it. I have to wipe about 3-5 times, each time with a clean paper towel, and I rinse the pan after every wipe. But it still has the fish smell.
Is there a better way to get the smell out, without soap or vinegar?
Thanks

You need to use soap.  You will not get the fish smell out without it.
The idea that you cannot use soap on cast iron is a myth.  Washing your pan with soap will not only help with smells, it will help maintain a better seasoning.

Thanks for this reply.  I did try that but it didn't work either.  My next idea is to just cook some chicken in it.

Huh. how did you cook the fish?  I make fish in my cast iron pan all the time, and have not had this issue.  Wondering what's different.

Besides washing with water and soap, I'd suggest heat. There's no way fish smell will still be present after putting the skillet in a hot oven (350F) for 45min or more.
Other solutions:

Let your cast iron skillet sit in boiling water for about 15 to 20 minutes.
Create a baking soda solution (5 parts water to 1 part baking soda) fill the skillet with the solution and boil it for 20-30 min. Let it rest overnight then wash it thoroughly.
mix vinegar + water (1:1) and boil in your pan for 20-30 min. Let it rest overnight and wash it.
squeeze 3 to 4 lemons and add the same amount of water, then leave it aside for an hour. Heat it for a few min and wash you skillet.
ultimately (but probably overkill) re-season your skillet. But probably any (or a combination) of the methods above will get rid of the smell before you resort to re-seasoning the skillet.


If you're worried about the smell of your cast-iron pans, I strongly recommend never soaking them, especially with soap. How smelly the food is shouldn't matter. Both of these actions intensify unpleasant smells in the pan (they don't reduce them). However, if you do happen to do this, an easy way to get rid of the smells is to heat the pan on the stovetop on high and smoke the smell out. You'll have to re-season the cooking surface of the pan afterward.
An easy way to reseason is to heat the pan as hot as it can get and take it outside with a spoonful of butter. Wait about 30 seconds, if the pan is really, really hot (to avoid the butter from bursting into flames, and never use cooking oil like this, because it will burst into flames and give you a powerful, but lumpy seasoning). Then add the butter and slide it around the pan, letting it smoke all over the place. Pour the molten black butter out and when it stops smoking, go inside and clean the excess off with running hot water and a scouring pad (don't use soap); then wipe the blackened excess off with a paper towel or toilet paper. It should have a rather nice slick seasoning that lasts a good while.
Anyway, what I recommend instead of soaking your pans is to violate what I personally consider to be a cast-iron myth (I don't consider the soap thing to be a myth, based on my experience with it; but to really say whether it's a myth we need to know in what ways it's supposed to be a myth; not just that it's a myth generally).
Anyway, after you cook the fish (the same as after the seasoning I described above), what I recommend is using such as a metal scouring pad, along with hot running water to scrub it down and get the fish pieces off. Don't use any soap. Don't worry about the smell for now (this should help you in the long-run). Worrying about the smell is part of the problem. You just need to keep cooking (not cleaning).
Anyway, the myth is that scouring pads will remove the seasoning, and while it's true that they can remove seasoning, the impact is pretty minimal if you do it regularly and season as afore described without soap or soaking (unless you do a weak seasoning at a lower temperature; the higher the temperature you season at, the stronger your seasoning will be, and the more resilient to scouring). Now, if you use soap, soaking and a scouring pad all at once, yeah, your seasoning is toast.
Soaking (especially with soap, but soap is not required) is one of the most effective ways to remove seasoning. The longer you soak, the more seasoning it removes. A short soak isn't the end of the world. A long soak means extra work for you (not less work). I know this because I've watched it happen zillions of times and compared it to not doing that zillions of times.
I do not recommend soaking pans, but I understand that it might seem like the easier way to remove stuff that gets stuck to your pan. Truth be told, it's not. Doing that provides for a viscious cycle that makes stuff stick to your pan more easily, and seem to make it require more soaking. You actually need to have faith that seasoning works, if you want to see that it works: Seasoning doesn't work best directly after seasoning. You need to cook some challenging things in it a couple times first, which will probably stick a little. But just scour it off with some water, and repeat. Then it should be pretty nice and slick from then on (and very easy to clean without soap or soaking), with hardly any effort in scouring.
Soaking can promote rust (I've seen it happen many times), but rust isn't really a big deal with big thick cast-iron pans. I know a lot of people think it's a heinous crime, but yeah. Just scrub it off with a scouring pad, season it, and cook. It won't hurt you. The pan will still survive, probably longer than an average human lifespan.
So, if you like cooking without much if any seasoning (some people do), in addition to having smelly pans, soaking your pan is perfectly fine (although there's potential to leech a lot of iron in your food, which could potentially be unsafe). However, there are easier alternatives, but you have to actually try them out the right way and not give up the moment you see something stick to a newly seasoned pan.
Oh, and another tip: one thing worse than soaking pans in soap for long periods with regard to its impact on your food's flavor/smell is to burn scrambled eggs in the same pan directly after and/or before soaking. It makes food cooked in the pan thereafter quite bitter and unpleasant (until you use heat to smoke it out again).
I'm guessing the people who say that it's a myth that soaking removes seasoning and that soap is a problem, don't soak their pans very long. The impact of a short soak is minimal by comparison with a long soak, even when using soap. But I personally think it still has a negative impact.
Having said all that, scouring pans isn't necessary with seasoned pans. It's just easier and more practical/no-nonsense (as long as you have a strong enough seasoning to handle the scouring); for a weaker seasoning, you should use some kind of plastic brush or whatever (and that's great for a stronger seasoning, too). You don't need to scour hard on a seasoned pan; it should be a pretty fast and easy process.
Anyway, regardless of whether soap hurts anything, soap isn't necessary by any means, for any of your cast-iron uses. You don't need to sterilize your pan via washing it. You don't need to remove every last speck of grease. Grease is good for cast-iron (but rinsing and/or wiping off the excess is perfectly fine).
However, whatever method you use, it's important to be consistent, and not mix and match half-hearted attempts of different methods. If you want the best of one world you've got to be in that world: If you're going to soak and use soap, do it the right way; don't oversoak (and probably never cook scrambled eggs in pans you soak with; when using soaking methods, scrambled eggs can easily make your pans smell fishy, even if you don't cook fish). If you're going to try out not-soaking your pans, don't think you can soak on occasion when the going gets tough, because that doesn't work and it makes it so you have to start all over again. You've got to tough it out if you want it to get easier (and don't assume it's going to be hard just because you've cooked something and it looks like the food is stuck to it; actually try to remove it without soap or soaking first; you may be surprised at how easy it is).
Scrambled eggs are great in pans that you never soak and never use soap with, however. They are one of the things that stick more easily directly after seasoning, though, but the more you cook scrambled eggs in the same pan on the same seasoning (without soaking, without soap), the less it sticks.

I have a cheap and easy solution for you that I guarantee you have all the equipment for in your house right now, my parents have been using this since I was a little kid: toothpaste. Use a dab of mint toothpaste in place of or in addition to dish washing detergent and wash with a sponge as usual, we do this all the time for any seafood fishy smells, including prawns and you can use it on other cutlery too. I wouldn't use sensitive teeth toothpaste though, just cause they are more expensive and a waste to use as cleaning material.

Huh, have you not found that the toothpaste abrades away the seasoning on cast iron?

@Sneftel I suspect that the point is to abrade the seasoning… take off the top layer that might have partially polymerized fish oil

@Joe Yes, I was asking about it destroying the seasoning as a whole.

@Sneftel If you mean does not abrade away the metal itself, then no it doesn't. I use it on cast iron pots as well as non-stick pans. In both situations, there are no burnt on solids, only the smell. The toothpaste does not erode the non-stick coating nor does it scratch the cast iron pan. If you are concerned it might, use one that does not specifically say it has "cleaning crystals".

@sneftel an abrasive pad doesn’t instantly destroy seasoning, and toothpaste is probably going to be more gentle than that (although, there are varying degrees of abrasive pads).  Hell, people sell chunks of chain mail to scour cast iron pans
